# How to perform click on specific location on screen using Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I want to perform click on activity just some pixels say 30px above bottom of screen. It is not text, not button/ImageButton. Just a blank layout whose Id is unknown. How to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robotium has a class called "Clicker". In this class, you have many options for click on a view or a coodinate of screen that you want. Please check it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.android.robotium/robotium-solo/1.6.0/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Clicker.java#Clicker.clickOnScreen%28float%2Cfloat%29)